# Problems in displaying record in tabular format in a jsp?

Tags: jsp

So, I want to read data from a text file and display the record in a table format in a JSP page. I tried the following code but for now it displays everything in one column. I want to display it a proper table format. Where am I doing wrong? Please can anyone correct my mistake.

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
<%

 FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaWebApp\\src\\java\\com\\servlets\\records.txt")));
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  String line = null;
  out.println("<table>");
  out.println("<tr>");

  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    //out.print(line + "<br/>");

    String[] data = line.split("\t");
    for (String val : data) {

        out.println("<td>" + val + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>" );
  }
  }
    out.println("</table>");
  br.close();





%>
```

These is how the records are saved in my text file

```
James  1  0098765  California
Maureen 2 0078657  Texas
```

The results of my code is displayed as follows

```
James
1
0098765
California
Maureen
2
0078657
Texas
```

Answer (score 0):

Small tweaks in your code as the table row is not well formed:

```
  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    out.println("<tr>"); //moved inside `while-loop`
    String[] data = line.split("\t");
    for (String val : data) {
        out.println("<td>" + val + "</td>");
    }
    out.println("</tr>" ); //moved outside of `for-loop`
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use Java code to generate HTML code. Read and process data first, then use JSTL to display them:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.util.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<%
  List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();

  String path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaWebApp\\src\\java\\com\\servlets\\records.txt";
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] data = line.split("\t");
    for (String val : data) {
      data.add(val);
    }
    lines.add(values);
  }
  request.addAttribute("lines", lines);
%>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <table>
      <c:forEach var="line" items="${lines}">
        <tr>
          <c:forEach var="value" items="${line}>
            <td>${value}</td>
          </c:forEach>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second, avoid putting business logic (i.e. reading and processing the file) into JSP at all - use [MVC pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOUIVsBN82Q), or at least extract the code into a separate Java class and call the method of that class to get the data for displaying.