# Unclosed String Literal error in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to dynamically update the value of my button in a gridview to a count value. Now, I get Unclosed String literal error at "  `out.println("<td>" + "<input type = button id = getid onclick=getbuttonid() value =  "<%=count%>" + ">" + "</td>");` My goal is to assign the value of count as the button value. What Am i doing wrong?

```
      <tr>
                <td colspan=4 align="center"
                    style="background-color:teal">
                    <b>User Record</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:lightgrey;">
                <td><b>Record Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>Card Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>MiddleName:</b></td>
                <td><b>BankAccountID:</b></td>
                <td><b>CurrencyID:</b></td>
                <td><b>DayTransactionLimit:</b></td>
                <td><b>Select:</b></td>


</tr>
  <%
      if(request.getParameter("mobilenumber")!=null)
              {
 FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(("C:\\Users\\Farheen\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Demo\\records.txt")));
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  String line = null;
  int count =0;
//  out.println("<table>");

  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    //out.print(line + "<br/>");
      out.println("<tr>");

    String[] data = line.split("\t");
    for (String val : data) {

        out.println("<td>" + val + "</td>");

        count ++;

  }
           out.println("<td>" + "<input type = button id = getid onclick=getbuttonid() value =  "<%=count%>" + ">" + "</td>");

   out.println("</tr>" );

  }
//    out.println("");
  br.close();




            }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have written in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40546843/3511123) to your other question, do not use Java code to generate HTML output. As you can see, it is **very** error prone.

Anyway, if you insist, then use

```
out.println("<td><input type =\"button\" id=\"getid\" onclick=\"getbuttonid()\" value=\"" + count + "\"></td>");
```

Comment: Thank  you very much. But when I click on the button to get the id, it shows the value to be 1 always.function getbuttonid(){
    var id = document.getElementById('getid').value;
    alert(id);
}

Comment: Well, the whole logic you are using is wrong. Maybe you should go through some tutorial(s) first, and then rethink what you need to do and how to achieve it. Anyway, in your case, you'll have more `<input id="getid" ... />` elements (one for each row in the `records.txt` file), and `document.getElementById('getid')` will get the first of them, which has `value="1"`, as the `count` is equal `1` at the moment of generating  that line. You need to have dynamic `id` for each row.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
out.println("<td>" + "<input type = button id = getid onclick=getbuttonid() value =  "<%=count%>" + ">" + "</td>");
```

to

```
out.println("<td>" + "<input type = button id = getid onclick=getbuttonid() value = "+ "<%=count%>" + ">" + "</td>");
```

Comment: Still shows the same error. Unclosed string literal.